# Is there a way to write a Spark dataframe to a .dat file?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I tried this, but it didn't work. From my understanding, `Spark` does not support the `.dat` file format. I do not want to write the file as a `.csv` or `.json`, then convert via a shell script later.

```
a.write.format("dat").save(outputPath)
```

Comment: DAT is a generic type that can be understood only by the application that it was created by. To start with it can be binary or text, depending on the application.
So, effective Spark will not be able to understand this format as it will be different for each application. Until and unless it is stored in one of the formats that Spark supports

Comment: There is no built in or direct support for what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Spark format function does not accepts "dat" as argument. You can have much more information in documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html

I'm sorry but easiest thing you can do is creating `csv` and converting it to `dat` later.